# El codigo del button funcionan en el Main pero no en el XML Android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, xml, style

tengo un codigo a un button en el cual funciona perfecto pero al querer pasarlo a XML no me funciona solo quiero pasar el codigo ya que al tener varios button aplica el mismo style y asi no copiar el mismo codigo por cada button

```
<Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button2"
            android:textColor="@color/verde_claro"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/btn.margin"
            android:background="@color/background_button"/>
```

ese es el codigo aplicado al Main y asi lo paso a XML

```
<style name="MyButton">
    <item name="android:layout_weight">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/verde_claro</item>
    <item name="android:layout_margin">@dimen/btn.margin</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/background_button</item>
</style>
```

le aplico el style con

```
<Button
            android:text="Button1"
            style="@style/MyButton"/>
```

pero no me muestra lo mismo, ya que tengo 2 botones, cada uno con el un codigo, el del main funciona correctamente, pero al que le aplico el style no se muestra correctamente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ahi se muestra como se ven los button, el 2 y 3 se muestran correctamente pero el 1 no se muestra siquiera, pero esta ahi, al añadir texto en su Text se crece hacia abajo

gracias de antemano

PD: es un curso de programacion que estoy haciendo, en los videos del curso funciona exactamente el mismo codigo correctamente...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Listo, ya resolví mi problema, aveces uno se enfrasca en las cosas mas simples pueden complicar a uno...

el error estaba en el style

```
 <item name="android:layout_weight">wrap_content</item>
```

ya que use la palabra WEIGTH en ves de WIDTH algo tan simple

asi quedo jaja

```
<item name="android:layout_widht">wrap_content</item>
```

en fin, una novatada, gracias por todo igual...